# Is there a database of cubic graphs on the web

Tags: graph-theory

I'm doing a research project in graph theory and need to program some stuff to help me study it. I used to have access to Mathematica but now I don't. So, when I'm programming things I'm entering the graph data in by hand which is really time consuming. So I was wondering if there was anywhere on the internet that contained a file I could download a file or files containing the descriptions of a variety cubic graphs to help automate this process.

Does anyone know of such a website?

Comment: I don't know about cubic graphs, but many contests publish their tests after the contest is over and many of those include graph data. More over you can turn any undirected graph into a cubic one by adding a simple features to vertices of degree $< 2$ and expanding vertices of larger degree into smal cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you don't have Mathematica anymore you can use the freely available Sage math which is probably the best tool for graph theory.

In sage you can generate cubic graphs of given order in the following manner:

```
sage: for G in graphs.nauty_geng("n -d3 -D3"):
# do something with G
```

where n is the order of the graphs you are interested in.

If you want a specific list of certain graphs take a look to B.D.Mckay page [here](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html)  and G. Royle's page [here](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/remote/cubics/).

The data here is represented in the graph6 format which can be used in the following way

```
sage: for line in open('yourfile.g6').readlines():
    G = Graph(line)
    # do something with G
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps big time.